# what does ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.2-apache mean?

Tags: docker, proxy

I'm a beginner with Docker and I don't understand this situation: when I try to build a image (on a Windows 10 host at workd) I get the error "ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.2-apache"

The problem is caused by the FROM clause in the Dockerfile:
"1 | >>> FROM php:8.2-apache"

When I try this same thing at home without a proxy connection (like at work) it runs ok.

I've found a workaround consisting in pulling the image before launching the Dockerfile which causes that the image is "redoownlodaded".

Comment: Your work machine seems to have TLS errors when communicating with docker.io. Check if your work machine has the latest Windows updates installed and also any Malware detection software that allows communications to docker.io

Comment: By the way, your hint is the last ERROR output on the screenshot, the internal one is more like what failed not what caused the failure

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  In between the small text and low-contrast colors, this is very hard to read.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the screen shot with the plain-text output of the build command?

Comment: Sorry I can't edit the question replacing the screenshot by the text since I won't have access the computer at work where the problem happened for the next weeks. I could remove the question if needed.

Comment: Image removed. The problem seems to be related to the proxy server I have at work (not at home). I found a workaround but the situation persists.